# How to compute autocorrelation with Nan values

Tags: python, numpy, nan, correlation

I would like to compute an autocorrelation [estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Estimation) in python. If the array has no NAN values, the autocorrelation can be computed explicitly via

```
def autocorr_naive(x):
    N = len(x)
    return np.array([np.mean(x[iSh:] * x[:N-iSh]) for iSh in range(N)])
```

Or using the numpy function `correlate`

```
def autocorr_numpy(x):
    N = len(x)
    return np.correlate(x, x, 'full')[N-1:] / N
```

The numpy function is significantly faster than the hand-written one, presumably because it uses [Wiener-Khinchine theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Efficient_computation) or similar to efficiently approximate the correlation.

**The problem** is that numpy.correlate [does not currently seem to handle](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14414) correlations if NAN values are present in the overlap. The naive extension to handle NAN values is simply to ignore them when calculating the mean

```
def autocorr_naive_nan(x):
    N = len(x)
    return np.array([np.nanmean(x[iSh:] * x[:N-iSh]) for iSh in range(N)])
```

The naive extension has two problems. Firstly, it is painfully slow compared to numpy implementation. Secondly, it has a lot of undesired wiggles at the tail, where the overlap consists of only a few points, and the estimate is naturally poor. The FFT based approximation used in numpy does not appear to be biased by these artifacts, at least not to the same extent.

**Pragmatic Question**: Is there a library I can use to compute the equivalent of `autocorr_naive_nan` in an efficient way?

Comment: this might be helpfull
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318362/2d-convolution-in-python-with-missing-data

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look